# BTM as the transaction manager in Tomcat 7?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, jta

Is there any documentation for configuring Bitronix Transaction Manager (BTM) in Tomcat 7?  Is BTM even compatible with Tomcat 7?

I found documentation for [How to use BTM as the transaction manager in Tomcat 6.x](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/Tomcat2x) but I haven't found anything for Tomcat 7.  Have the procedures changed for Tomcat 7?

The Tomcat 6 docs specify btm-tomcat55-lifecycle-2.1.0.jar, I wonder if there is a newer version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything in there that wouldn't work with Tomcat 7. The only slight oddity is the reference to "You have to put your datasources configurations in Tomcat's conf/resources.properties file." That isn't now and never has been a Tomcat configuration file. I suspect it is a BTM config file.

Comment: many thanks. after you mentioned the conf/resources.properties i realized i had a typo in setenv.bat where i set CATALINA_OPTS to point to the btm-config.properties.